# Get Data From OPC-UA Server using C#, without GUI

Tags: c#, opc-ua

We have a background service, which has the single purpose of getting recent data from a server.

Now the server should be an OPC-UA server. Unfortunaly, the SDKs and examples I found to connect to this are limited/only explained in ways that are heavily integrated with a classic windows forms application. Up to the point where its impossible to separate GUI from business logic.

At this point I'm wondering if we are misusing the client functionality and should opt for a different way?

Ideally I'd like to wrap the whole OPC-UA Logic inside a class library and just call GetData(), is that impossible?

Comment: There should be no reason that a OPC-UA client needs any kind of UI, and it should be perfectly possible to wrap it in a library. But it is not very clear what you are asking. Do you have to use a UI? - No. Should you? - maybe, it depends.

Comment: From outside it does seem like the core classes depend on application specific things, like the app-config or app license managers. It's very intransparent imo

Comment: Well, reading and understanding code can be difficult but valuable skill. I would suggest to make a small console program and try to reproduce the simplest functionality possible from the example you got. App-config is just a way to store key+value in a file, so just copy the values if you are testing things out.

Comment: I'm proficient enough in reading code to see if a code violates 90% of good practices ( probably related to their desire to promote foundation members commercial products :) ).
I was just feeling lost if the whole of OPC-UA forces one into a certain workflow or not.

Comment: What the foundation develops are primarily the specifications. Their .NET stack and SDK are a "bonus". It is largely community-developed, with OPC Foundation only providing the necessary minimal work to keep the stack parts up the latest released spec.

Comment: @ZbynekZ "largely community-developed" is a little misleading - it's primarily developed by paid Microsoft employees.

Comment: @Kevin Herron: Yeah OK, I admit I haven't checked the actual proportion of contributions, so you are most likely right.

Comment: My only point is that while the examples may not be to OP's liking, the stack/SDK itself is not low quality. But if he needs his hand held and a support contract then he should pay a vendor.

Comment: In order to make your client effective, follow the observer pattern which is the way to monitor any changes to values by setting up a subscription and getting callbacks whenever the subscribed values change. You should not synchronously poll the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [Tutorials for Client development](https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdknet/3.2.0/html/L1ClientTutorials.html), specifically [Console Client](https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdknet/3.2.0/html/L2ClientTutConsoleClient.html) useful. This is a much better SDK than the one from the OPC Foundation. You will find full C# samples including a console client application (no GUI).

You might want to re-evalute your needs for

> Ideally I'd like to wrap the whole OPC-UA Logic inside a class library and just call GetData(), is that impossible?

It is totally possible, but with OPC-UA, you have to keep in mind that it is recommended to get data using a subscription model (Monitored Items) instead of performing an explicit Read for a value (unless you just want to read an attribute once). So, I would make sure that however you are building your client-side class makes sense for the needs of your application.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably referring to the "SDK" provided by the OPC Foundation - but you have not stated that explicitly in your question; in fact, you used the term "SDKs", in plural. There certainly are also commercial SDKs which might be better in this respect.

Here is one (QuickOPC), together with one-liner example of reading the OPC UA data: https://www.opclabs.com/products/quickopc/opc-specifications/unified-architecture/generic-data . Disclaimer: This is a self-promotion.

Comment: There are other (commercial) SDKs with the same quality als the OPC Foundation "SDK".. I'm happy to test out yours, thank you!